# File output not appearing

Tags: arrays, c, file

I have a problem, i am not sure how to print in file.
I tried many ways, nothing worked!
Here is my code ,i try to print in file the 2D array board.

```
fp = fopen("minesweeper.txt", "w+");

if (fp == NULL) {
    return 1;
    printf("ERROR");
}   
    
for (i = 0; i < yi; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < xi; j++)
        fprintf(fp, "%c  ",board);
            
    fprintf(fp, "\n");
}

fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Please note that `printf("ERROR");` following a `return` will do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
fclose(fp);
```

after the loop block.

It will close the stream and all buffers are flushed.

Comment: okey i fixed it thanks for pointing out the fclose(fp);.The problem was that i put it in the end of the code after return 0;.